# Audio Stream to Base64 String issue in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, base64, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating Windows Phone 8.1 app, I have created Audio Recorder module, and converting audio stream to Base64String, but my resulting Base64String is given below:

```
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

For exact idea, see my code below:

```
public void UpdateWavHeader()
{
    if (!stream.CanSeek) throw new Exception("Can't seek stream to update wav header");

    var oldPos = stream.Position;

    stream.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)stream.Length - 8), 0, 4);

    stream.Seek(40, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)stream.Length - 44), 0, 4);

    stream.Seek(oldPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    string isoVideoFileName = "DemoFile.aac";

    if (isf.FileExists(isoVideoFileName))
    {
        isf.DeleteFile(isoVideoFileName);
    }

    isoVideoFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(isoVideoFileName, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
    isoVideoFile.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);

    byte[] chunk = new byte[isoVideoFile.Length];
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(chunk);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these two lines in your code:

```
byte[] chunk = new byte[isoVideoFile.Length];
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(chunk);
```

You are basicly encoding a byte array initialized to zero's.

EDIT:

Assuming you want to encode the stream you are writing to the .aac file, this should do the trick:

```
var chunk = stream.ToArray();

isoVideoFile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(isoVideoFileName, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
isoVideoFile.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);

//byte[] chunk = new byte[isoVideoFile.Length];
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(chunk);
```

Comment: MarkO, Thanks bro, what should I need to do? Can you show me by code?